# What numerical quadrature algoritm can be use to handle $\int_b^c K_0 (x-a)-K_1(x-a) dx$?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am curious what numerical algorithm can be used to handle $$\int_b^c [K_0 (x-a)-K_1(x-a)] dx$$, where $a\lt b\lt c$ and K is the modified bessel function of the second kind.

From plotting the function the integrand seems to go to $-\infty$ at x=a so I would assume you could not use the trapezoidal rule or simpsons rule to handle this, correct? I am interested because I would like to write my own code to do this numerically.

Is it possible to handle this with Gauss-Legendre quadrature?

Comment: The question has to do with the method of evaluating the integral numerically. As I mentioned in the question, I would like to understand how to deal with this specific case so I can write a code on my own and not use mathematica. I am just curious about the best way to go about evaluating this numerically. If you would like I could remove the part of the question on mathematica and the question still stands. Essentially I am asking how do you deal with this singular endpoint integral numerically?

Comment: Edited, although not much changed.

Comment: Generally speaking, if the integrand is ill-behaved slightly outside the interval but is well-behaved inside it, an adaptive quadrature of some variety is effective.

Comment: If the blow-up happens outside the interval, it doesn't rule out using the trapezoid rule or something similar. It depends on how far away the point at infinity is... for instance, you can integrate $\frac{1}{x}$ quite happily between $x=10$ and $x=15$. That's not to say it's the best possible approach. A Gaussian quadrature rule may work, but an adaptive approach is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

*In principle*, you could use Gauss-Legendre (or midpoint rule, or any other method that does not require evaluation of $f$ at the endpoints of the interval). But this is  inefficient for improper integrals. The appropriate strategy is *adaptive integration*:

1. divide the interval into two halves,
2. calculate integral on each half (using one of the aforementioned methods)
3. compare the sum of halves to the (separately evaluated) integral over the whole interval
4. if the difference is acceptable, stop (on that interval), otherwise repeat the partition process

There are many online sources on adaptive integration, [here is one](http://online.sfsu.edu/meredith/Numerical_Analysis/improper_integrals.pdf).